# Android Application HTTP Methods

Tags: android, rest, http

I am working on a big android application project.  I have my android app and also I have a node JS API on my server.  I want to make a Restful API so I want to make HTTP requests from my android application to node JS API.  I am searching for many weeks and trying different solutions for the HTTP requests from android but I am not sure what is the best solution.  Any suggestions from personal experience for the best solution to make HTTP requests from android with good documentation? (for example an API, library, AyncTask etc.)

I am developing using Java.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit and OkHttp3 client is actually a some kind of standard for this. I suppose you can refer to [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) to take a look on it.

Comment: Thank you very much i will probably go for Retrofit. It's pretty easy compare to other methods!

Comment: Retrofit is just an abstraction over `REST` interface definition expressed in the programming language you are going to use. Internally it uses OkHttp3 as a network client (if this was not changed directly) - just to bring some clarity :)
But yes, Retrofit allows to create a `REST` client quite fast without diving into unnecessary details.

Answer (score 1):

**Best HTTP Library For *Android* :**

- **Retrofit**
- **OKHttp**
- **Volley**

This [Link](https://medium.com/@sotti/android-networking-ii-okhttp-retrofit-moshi-and-picasso-c381f6c0efd8) showing all advantage and disadvantage about their libraries.